# How to split a string according to some pattern template using Java regex?

Tags: java, regex, java-8, pattern-matching

My strings have the same template when creating them - for example:

```
String example1 = "AAB/CC/0x12345/DD/str1-str2-str2-str4"

String example2 = "AAB/CC/0x567735646/DD/ss1-sssss2-sssssss3-ssssssss4"
```

All the strings start with `"AAB/CC"`, have `"/DD/"` in the middle and the suffix is spitted by 4 `"-"`.

I wanted to write a class that can recognize these kind of string among hundrends of other string and to fill a new class with the data of the template - for exmaple :

```
class A {
   String firstStr = 0x567735646
   String firstFromSuffix = ss1
   String secondFromSuffix = sssss
   String thirdFromSuffix = sssssss3
   String fourthFromSuffix = ssssssss4
}
```

My first idea was to use separators and substrings like this :

for checking if this has the correct template:

```
 String mySuffix = fullKey.substring(fullKey.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
 String[] suffixSplit = mySuffix .split("-");
 return suffixSplit.length == 4;
```

And for filling class A it got uglier..

```
 String dataChunkSuffix = fullKey.substring(fullKey.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
 String dataChunkPrefix = fullKey.substring(0, fullKey.lastIndexOf("/"));
 String firstStr= dataChunkPrefix.substring(dataChunkPrefix.lastIndexOf("/") + 1);
 String[] suffixSplit = dataChunkSuffix.split("-");
 String firstFromSuffix= suffixSplit[0];
 String secondFromSuffix= suffixSplit[1];
```

Can you please advise how to do it better using regex?

Comment: so basically from the String you need a class that will contain the String if it matches the regex and it's suffixes?

Comment: Perhaps, you’re thinking too complicated. You can to `array = fullKey.split("/"); firstStr = array[2]; array = array[4].split("-");` Then, you already have everything…

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^AAB/CC/(.+)/DD/(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)$");
    Matcher m = p.matcher(example2);

    if (m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1)); // all groups up to 5
    }
```

This would be so much more fluent IMO in java-9:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^AAB/CC/(.+)/DD/(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)-(.+?)$");

try (Scanner scan = new Scanner(example2);) {
      scan.findAll(p)
          .map(mr -> new A(mr.group(1), mr.group(2), mr.group(3), mr.group(4), mr.group(5)));
}
```

Comment: ohh it returns false for m.find() =[

Comment: @user1386966 for what input?

Comment: my bad..sorry..used case sensitive string. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can use this RegExp, because the following parts only contain word letters and numbers: 0x12345  str1  str2  str2  str4

```
^AAB/CC/(\w+)/DD/(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)-(\w+)$
```